# How to pass data from server code to ejs template?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, frontend, ejs

I have a simple server and and I get the data on url through browser perfectly. I am trying to get the data in my ejs template.

This is how I am getting the data:

```
app.get('/some', function(req, res, next) {
var size = 3;
var curr = req.query.page || 1;

var allSome = Object.assign([], jsFile.some);
some = allSome.slice((curr - 1) * size, curr * size);

some = some.map(function(som) {
    var mapSome = Object.assign({}, som);
    delete mapSome.var1;
    delete mapSome.var2;
    return mapSome;
});

return res.json({
    some: some,
    total: allSome.length,
});
});
```

This is how I am trying to pass the data:

```
app.get('/some', function (req, res, next) {
    res.render('events', {data : res.json.some});
});
```

This is how I am trying to get the data:

```
<ul>
    <% data.forEach(function(dat) { %>
    <li><%= dat.var3 %></li>
    <li><%= dat.var4%>
    <% }); %>
</ul>
```

But I am getting:

> Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined

I am new to ejs and front end. I would really appreciate if someone could help me in this.

Comment: You have 2 routes with the same url, so express will only handle one of it

Comment: @vengleabso So do I need to add the rendering code inside the one where I get the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This block of code will repond with `json` not pass it to next `middleware`

```
return res.json({
  some: some,
  total: allSome.length,
});
```

Replacing the above block with the following should do:

```
res.render('events', {data : some});
```

Answer (score 0):

### `index.js` file:

```js
let express = require("express");
let app = express();

app.set("viwe engine", "ejs");
app.listen(80, () => {
    console.log("iam ok! *:80")
});

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.render("index.ejs", {
        data: {
            data: {
                "glossary": {
                    "title": "example glossary",
                    "GlossDiv": {
                        "title": "S",
                        "GlossList": {
                            "GlossEntry": {
                                "ID": "SGML",
                                "SortAs": "SGML",
                                "GlossTerm": "Standard Generalized Markup Language",
                                "Acronym": "SGML",
                                "Abbrev": "ISO 8879:1986",
                                "GlossDef": {
                                    "para": "A meta-markup language, used to create markup languages such as DocBook.",
                                    "GlossSeeAlso": ["GML", "XML"]
                                },
                                "GlossSee": "markup"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    })
})
```

### `index.ejs` file:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>HI</h1>

    <input id="EJSData" value="<%= JSON.stringify(data) %>"/>
    <script id="EJSDataLoader">
        (()=>{
            let ejsDataElm = document.getElementById("EJSData");
            let scElm = document.createElement("script");
            scElm.innerHTML = `const EJSData = ()=>{return ${ejsDataElm.value}}`;
            document.body.appendChild(scElm);
            document.body.removeChild(document.getElementById("EJSData"));
            document.body.removeChild(document.getElementById("EJSDataLoader"));
        })();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

### Results:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bFfHp.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/I57vW.png

Answer (score 0):

You don´t write the li close tag

```
<ul>
    <% data.forEach(function(dat) { %>
    <li><%= dat.var3 %></li>
    <li><%= dat.var4%></li>
    <% }); %>
</ul>
```